# dict of DataFrames structure to compare xlsx sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have several excel files that have multiple sheets in each file. Each sheet should have the same columns (though different lengths), but some files have different numbers of sheets and the sheets have different names so I don't want to have to specify which sheet is which.

I know that if I read the file in with

```
read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name=None, header=headerrow)
```

it will read in all the sheets and make a dict of DataFrames, but I can't figure out what that structure practically means for accessing.

If I want to compare a column from sheet1 and sheet2, and they have the same header, how can I access the values separately to compare/manipulate them?

Ultimately I want to say if the value of a cell in col1 in shee1 is within 2ppm of the value of any cell in col1 in sheet 2, put the corresponding row from sheet1 and sheet2 somewhere new (either a new df, new sheet, not picky about where it ends up).

Comment: Each dataframe is the value in dict, so you access any given value (dataframe) just like you would for any dict. `df_dict['my_df']` is equivalent to `df`. Use any dataframe methods. `df_dict['my_df']['my_column']` or `df_dict['my_df'].describe()`

Comment: Do this answer your question? [pandas read_excel(sheet name = None) returns a dictionary of strings, not dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768950)

Comment: 99% of the way there, I think. since I don't know the names of the sheets (they're changing), I can use the loop from the link you posted, but how can I compare between them since normally I'd do something like if df1['col1'] == df2['col1']. How cna I call them separately for comparison purposes?

Comment: Are you comparing between sheets in the same file or between sheets in different files? Also, are there multiple dataframe dicts (from multiple files)?

Comment: One file, a couple different sheets (with different names, but the names are changing from file to file so I don't want to define them specifically). I'm just trying to write the code to handle one file at a time, so it's just one dataframe dict.

Comment: After fiddling for a long time, I realized that my ultimate goal was better served by flattening the dict of dfs into one big df with a column for keys. But hopefully this helps someone else who is looking for this in the future. Thanks for the help @TrentonMcKinney

Comment: The dataframes can easily be flattened with `df = pd.concat(df_dict.values())`